# How to remove a value from a list in a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have created a dataframe:

```
[in] testing_df =pd.DataFrame(test_array,columns=['transaction_id','product_id'])

# Split the product_id's for the testing data
testing_df.set_index(['transaction_id'],inplace=True)
testing_df['product_id'] = testing_df['product_id'].apply(lambda row: row.split(','))

[out]                 product_id
transaction_id                 
001                       [P01]
002                  [P01, P02]
003             [P01, P02, P09]
004                  [P01, P03]
005             [P01, P03, P05]
006             [P01, P03, P07]
007             [P01, P03, P08]
008                  [P01, P04]
009             [P01, P04, P05]
010             [P01, P04, P08]
```

How can I now remove 'P04' and 'P08' from the results?

I tried:

```
# Remove P04 and P08 from consideration
testing_df['product_id'] = testing_df['product_id'].map(lambda x: x.strip('P04'))

testing_df['product_id'].replace(regex=True,inplace=True,to_replace=r'P04,',value=r'')
```

However, neither option seems to work.

The datatypes are:

```
[in] print(testing_df.dtypes)
[out] product_id    object
dtype: object

[in] print(testing_df['product_id'].dtypes)
[out] object
```

Comment: Please help me understand if `product_id` is a column of lists or strings.

Comment: `product_id` is a column of lists of strings, ie- `['P01','P02','P03']`

Comment: You should print out the types of your columns for clarity.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ also please look at my other question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45486506/algorithm-to-compare-dataframe-and-dictionary-and-return-missing-value-for-subst?noredirect=1#comment77934693_45486506)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

store all your elements to be removed in a list.

```
remove_results = ['P04','P08']
for k in range(len(testing_df['product_id'])):
    for r in remove_results:
        if r in testing_df['product_id'][k]:
            testing_df['product_id][k].remove(r)
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I would do it **before** splitting:

Data:

```
In [269]: df
Out[269]:
                 product_id
transaction_id
1                       P01
2                   P01,P02
3               P01,P02,P09
4                   P01,P03
5               P01,P03,P05
6               P01,P03,P07
7               P01,P03,P08
8                   P01,P04
9               P01,P04,P05
10              P01,P04,P08
```

Solution:

```
In [271]: df['product_id'] = df['product_id'].str.replace(r'\,*?(?:P04|P08)\,*?', '') \
                                             .str.split(',')

In [272]: df
Out[272]:
                     product_id
transaction_id
1                         [P01]
2                    [P01, P02]
3               [P01, P02, P09]
4                    [P01, P03]
5               [P01, P03, P05]
6               [P01, P03, P07]
7                    [P01, P03]
8                         [P01]
9                    [P01, P05]
10                        [P01]
```

**alternatively** you can change:

```
testing_df['product_id'] = testing_df['product_id'].apply(lambda row: row.split(','))
```

with:

```
testing_df['product_id'] = testing_df['product_id'].apply(lambda row: list(set(row.split(','))- set(['P04','P08'])))
```

Demo:

```
In [280]: df.product_id.apply(lambda row: list(set(row.split(','))- set(['P04','P08'])))
Out[280]:
transaction_id
1               [P01]
2          [P01, P02]
3     [P09, P01, P02]
4          [P01, P03]
5     [P01, P03, P05]
6     [P07, P01, P03]
7          [P01, P03]
8               [P01]
9          [P01, P05]
10              [P01]
Name: product_id, dtype: object
```

Comment: Wait. `product_id` is a list. Use `astype(str)` first and then `apply(ast.literal_eval)` after

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, it became a list after: `testing_df['product_id'].apply(lambda row: row.split(','))`

Comment: @zsad512, do you mean it is a list before you execute `testing_df['product_id'].apply(lambda row: row.split(','))` ???

Comment: @MaxU i think it is a list of strings both before and after...first its one string `"P01,P02,P03"` and then it becomes 3 strings `"P01","P02","P03"`

Comment: @zsad512, OK thanks for clarification - my assumption was correct then...

Comment: I tried `df['product_id'].str.replace(r'(?:P04|P08)\,', '').str.split(',\s*')` A) PO4 and P08 are still present in the data, as they are in your output in your answer, B) The structure of the dataframe changes in an unwanted fashion

Comment: @zsad512, "A)" - should be fixed now. Could you clarify "B)" please?

Comment: The structure of the df should be kept exactly as is because it must be compared to another df which is structured the same as well. Please see the answer I accepted for further clarification. Also, please look at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45486506/algorithm-to-compare-dataframe-and-dictionary-and-return-missing-value-for-subst?noredirect=1#comment77934693_45486506)

Answer (score 0):

A list comprehension will likely be most efficient:

```
exc = {'P04', 'P08'}
df['product_id'] = [[i for i in L if i not in exc] for L in df['product_id']]
```

Note that an inefficient Python-level loop is unavoidable. `apply` + `lambda`, `map` + `lambda` or an in-place solution all involve a Python-level loop.